# Accessing Variables?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an SDI application which creates several modeless dialogs.
Each one of these dialogs can create another modeless dialog called CMyDialog.
All works well except many instances of CMyDialog can be created (from each different original dialog).

I would like to have only one CMyDialog.

The way I have been thinking of approaching this problem is to create a bool flag b_CMyDialog, and then only create a CMyDialog if b_CMyDialog = false.
The problem is I do not know where to put b_CMyDialog variable, and how to access it.

Can someone please help?

Thank you
a.

Answer (score 1):

Any place in an MFC program can call AfxGetMainWnd() to get a pointer to the main window. So you could put the bool variable there to be able to access it from anywhere.

Better yet, you could put a function there that creates the CMyDialog.

Even better yet, instead of using a bool you can use the pointer to the CMyDialog that you get when you create it. Just make sure you NULL that pointer in the main window constructor and whenever the dialog is destroyed.